# Set background color for subplot

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

Say I have an image made of 4 sub plots like so:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
# Simple data to display in various forms
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

# Four axes, returned as a 2-d array
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axarr[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
axarr[0, 1].scatter(x, y)
axarr[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
axarr[1, 0].plot(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0]')
axarr[1, 1].scatter(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1]')
# Fine-tune figure; hide x ticks for top plots and y ticks for right plots
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in axarr[0, :]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_yticklabels() for a in axarr[:, 1]], visible=False)

plt.show()
```

which returns this:

[image]

I want to add a grey background to one of this plots, say the bottom left one, since I like the way `R` makes some images look (see [here](http://lahman.r-forge.r-project.org/doc/figure/Batting-unnamed-chunk-1.png) for example). I haven't found an easy way to do this with `matplotlib`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply do [`axarr[1,0].set_facecolor('grey')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axis_bgcolor) to change the axis color for any particular axis manually.

`matplotlib` accepts many different color strings (examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp)) as well as `hex` values in HTML strings (for example `'#eeefff'`).
[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks Sir. Update the function name has been replaced from 'set_axis_bgcolor' to 'set_facecolor' [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10762#issuecomment-370980311) Also thanks @nrflaw

Answer (score 7):

Axes.set_axis_bgcolor() has been deprecated since version 2.0. Use [set_facecolor()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_facecolor.html) now.