# How do I change the color surrounding just one subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, background-color, subplot

I have a matplotlib figure with 16 subplots (4 columns, 4 rows). I would like to change the color surrounding just one of the subplots (the one located at row 2, column 2). So, something like the green in this Stack Overflow question: [How to change plot background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color)

How would I go about doing that, without changing the surrounding colors of any of the other subplots?

I do not want to change the background color of the subplot - only the outside of the subplot, as shown in the link provided above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set background color for subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313586/set-background-color-for-subplot)

Comment: You will need to place a rectangle of one fourth of the figure size in each dimension behind the axes.