# change background color of matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to change the background color of the embeded matplotlob graph. I already got it to change the background color of the widget, but not of the chart (inside)[I mean the white part of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9klUn.png)

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

root = Tk()
root.title("graph embed")
root.geometry("200x300")
root.configure(bg="yellow")

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('yellow')
fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y, "bo")
fig.set_facecolor("yellow")

chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
chart.get_tk_widget().pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y, "bo", color="red")

Comment: I mean the white box around the points, not the color of the point

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23313630/5202279

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating two separe axes and changing the facecolor on the wrong one. Try this:

```
(...)
root.configure(bg="yellow")

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, "bo")
fig.set_facecolor("yellow")
ax.set_facecolor('yellow')

chart = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
(...)
```